# how to use UIDevice's advertising identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidevice

I would like to know what are those restrictions for using UIDevice's advertising identifier string. Do I have to use it solely for ad tracking purpose ? can I use the advertising identifier for other non-ad purpose ? thank you .

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code.    And you need add the framework called AdSupport And It only opens for iOS6 or Later .So if you want to use it as a unique code for Device. You need use uniqueDeviceIdentifier for IOS5 or Before.

```
[[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString];
```

Comment: will apple allow this?